# Prevent git from asking for the GnuPG password during signing a commit

Tags: git, github, gnupg

Git always asks me to enter a passphrase to unlock my secret key while signing a commit using.

```
git commit -S -m 'message'
```

How can I store in cache the password so that I don't have to enter it each and every time while signing the commit

Comment: You could set up `gpg-agent` and configure the `default-cache-ttl` option along with `max-cache-ttl` to cache your password.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it using git. Like git password caching.

Answer (score 53):

Git never gets hold of the GnuPG passphrase. You must rely on GnuPG's capabilities of caching passphrases, which happens through `gpg-agent` which are easily set up by editing `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` (hidden somewhere in your `AppData` folder in Windows).

Set `default-cache-ttl` to the number of seconds the passphrase is cached after each invocation of GnuPG. `maximum-cache-ttl` sets the time after the passphrase was initially entered at which the cache is wiped. Make sure `ignore-cache-for-signing` is not set -- otherwise GnuPG will ignore the cache for signing operations.

If you want to sign commits without any user interaction, you can prefill the cache through `gpg-preset-passphrase`, often hidden somewhere in a location like `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase`; or by running an arbitrary decryption or signing operation. You might also configure git to use an option like `--passphrase [your passphrase]` to be passed to `gpg`, but read up on the restrictions and security implications of this approach (it involves your passphrase being stored in plaintext somewhere).

Full list of options is [here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html).

Comment: I don't have `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, instead I have `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, is it ok to set `default-cache-ttl` in that.?

Comment: No, these options are explicitely for `gpg-agent.conf`. Do you have `gpg-agent` installed (`which gpg-agent` should list an entry)? Otherwise, just create a new file and set up these options.

Comment: Yeah, I have gpg-agent installed, but it's not working, neither in the file gpg-agent.conf, nor in the gpg.conf. By the way, I am using Ubuntu gnome 16.04, are you sure this method work on it.?

Comment: Yes, this should work. It might work out better if you configure git to use GnuPG 2 (`gpg2`), there was a question on this just a few days ago.

Comment: Just for info, on Fedora gpg-preset-passphrase is located under `/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase`

Comment: *prefill the cache through gpg-preset-passphrase*? How to do that? Exactly?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions as follow-up comments, ask a new question instead.

Comment: nit: typo `maximum-cache-ttl` -> `max-cache-ttl`

Answer (score 6):

After updating to Ubuntu 18.04 all my previous solutions no longer worked, because `gnome-keyring` no longer implements a GPG agent, and I couldn't get `gpg-agent` to cache any passphrase.

Here's the solution that finally worked for me:

Create a script `gpg-without-tty`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $(secret-tool lookup gpgpassphrase $GPGKEY) | /usr/bin/gpg --batch \
    --no-tty --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-fd 0 "$@"
```

Set your passphrase for $GPGKEY in gnome-keyring:

`secret-tool store --label='Passphrase for GPG Key' gpgpassphrase $GPGKEY`

Tell git to use the `gpg-without-tty` script:

`git config --global gpg.program /path/to/gpg-without-tty`

You might also have to add the `allow-loopback-pinentry` setting to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.

**Update:** While this worked locally it turns out that it somehow messed up the signatures: it signed the commits with the full 40-character fingerprint. GitHub didn't recognize these signatures as being valid. And when I looked at older commits that I had signed before updating to 18.04 (`git log --show-signature`) they no longer showed up as valid. I ended up removing the `gpg.program` setting in the git config. Turns out the problems I encountered were probably related to having that setting in the first place (which I used in the past to work around a different problem).

So, in short, running `git config --global --unset gpg.program` was the answer to my problems after the update.

Answer (score 6):

[From the GitHub Website](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits#:%7E:text=gpgsign%20true.-,To%20store%20your%20GPG,-key%20passphrase%20so):

> To store your GPG key passphrase so you don't have to enter it every time you sign a commit, use the following tools:
>
> - For Mac users, the [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/) allows you to store your GPG key passphrase in the Mac OS Keychain.
> - For Windows users, the [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/) integrates with other Windows tools.
>
> You can also manually configure [gpg-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent) to save your GPG key passphrase, but this doesn't integrate with Mac OS Keychain like ssh-agent and requires more setup.

Comment: I have my gpg key passphrase in keychain, however after a restart I am prompted every time I commit.  What do I need to do to get it to check my key chain for the passhrase?

Answer (score 0):

an enhanced version of the script in [decocijo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57927025/9609574) that doesn't break `git log`. note that it reads the passphrase from an environment variable `$GPG_PASS`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export pflag=""
# create dynamic `--passphrase` flag to insert into the final command if the passphrase variable is not empty.
if [[ -n "$GPG_PASS" ]];  then
    pflag="--passphrase ${GPG_PASS}"
fi

# "<&0" → use same stdin as the one originally piped to script
# "$@" → pass all script arguments to actual command

gpg --yes --batch $pflag $@ <&0

exit $?
```

then run `git config --local gpg.program /path/to/gpg-without-tty`